# combine a set of row statuses into a single summary status

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a view that looks like this:

```
package_id  package_line  status_a        status_b
1           1             NOT_STARTED     FAILED
1           2             STARTED         STARTED
1           3             FAILED          NOT_STARTED
2           1             COMPLETE        STARTED
2           2             COMPLETE        NOT_STARTED
```

and so on, for several thousand rows.  Status_a and status_b are separate unrelated statuses (in fact they are whether a package executed on system a and on system b).

I need a summary by package_id, to roll up to

```
   package_id status_a  status_b
   1          FAILED    FAILED
   2          COMPLETE  NOT_STARTED
```

The rules for combining package lines are

```
 1. If any package line has failed, the package has failed.
 2. If all package lines are complete, the package is complete.
 3. If all package lines are NOT_STARTED, the package has not started.
 4. Otherwise, the package is started (i.e. a combination of started, not_started, and complete would summarize as STARTED).
```

So I'm trying to come up with a query to create this summary.  I'd love to post a code sample, but I'm really at loss.  Presumably I want to GROUP_BY the package_id, but what can I use as an aggregate function that would allow me to apply the rules listed?

If it helps, I do have control over how the statuses are reported at the package line level, so I could report a numeric status (though I like having it human readable just for sanity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (same for `status_b`):

```
SELECT package_id,
       CASE WHEN FAILED_COUNT > 0 THEN 'FAILED'
            WHEN COMPLETE_COUNT = ALL_COUNT THEN 'COMPLETE'
            WHEN NOT_STARTED_COUNT = ALL_COUNT THEN 'NOT_STARTED'
            ELSE 'STARTED'
       END status_a
FROM (            
SELECT package_id,
     COUNT(status_a) ALL_COUNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN status_a = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FAILED_COUNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN status_a = 'COMPLETE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) COMPLETE_COUNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN status_a = 'NOT_STARTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NOT_STARTED_COUNT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN status_a = 'STARTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) STARTED_COUNT
 FROM table
GROUP BY package_id
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Fixed a couple of misplaced commas, in case anyone else wants to use this one day.